# R: Faster Rolling VWAP

Tags: r, volume

Given the following data

```
N<-1000;
Px<-runif(N, min = 100, max = 120);
Vol<-runif(N, min = 1, max = 20)
```

I generate a VWAP series rolling from index =1 with

```
VWAP<-unlist(lapply(seq(1,length(Px)),function(x) sum(Px[1:x]*Vol[1:x])/sum(Vol[1:x])))
```

This works well for N<10000 but as N approaches 1M the efficiency dramatically decreases.
Any suggestions for a faster implementation?

Comment: @HubertL Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax which doesn't recalculate sums of previous elements at each iteration:

```
  N<-1000000;
  Px<-runif(N, min = 100, max = 120);
  Vol<-runif(N, min = 1, max = 20)
  PxVol <- Px*Vol
  SPxVol <- cumsum(PxVol)
  SVol <- cumsum(Vol)
  VWAP <- SPxVol/SVol
```